# IEnumerable<T, int>, Arity and Generic Type Definitions

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-entities

I have a class *Counter* that counts things by key.  Simplified:

```
public class Counter<T> {
    private Dictionary<T, int> counts;

    public void Increment(T key) {
        int current;
        bool exists = counts.TryGetValue(key, out current);
        if (exists) {
            counts[key]++;
        } else {
            counts[key] = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

It does a number of other things specialized to my needs, but that's the essence.  So far, it works great.

Now I want to enable it to be used in a Linq query (with both the keys and the values).  Do to that, I think I need to implement

```
IEnumerable<T, int>
```

So I added:

```
public class Counter<T> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>> {
    // ...
    IEnumerator<KeyValuePair<T, int>> 
    IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>>.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return ((IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>>)counts).GetEnumerator();
    }
    System.Collections.IEnumerator 
    System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
    {
        return counts.GetEnumerator();
    }
```

Which unfortunately leads to the compiler error

> The number of generic arguments provided doesn't equal the arity of the generic type definition.
>   Parameter name: instantiation

**Questions**

1. What the heck is arity?
2. Am I on the right path to make this type usable from Linq?
3. How do I fix the implementation?

**UPDATE**: Typo

I had a typo while simplifying my code to post.  The code is in fact attempting to implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>>` and not `IEnumerable<T, int>`

Comment: On #1. IEnumerable<T>. *One* T. That's the *arity.* You're trying to provide <T, int>.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: There's only one *generic type argument*.  The other type *int* is fixed.  Is that not allowed?  Can you help me out with a reference?

Comment: **Downvoter**: I would appreciate knowing what you find lacking in this question.

Comment: The fact that one is T and one is int is not relevant. You could have filled in the T, as well, but you are still providing one too many.

Comment: For #3, perhaps start instead by using `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>>`, which matches your GetEnumerator implementation and would allow you to use your pairs in a query, if that's what you intend to do. It's hard to give you specifics on the best approach since we don't see how you intend to use it in the query.

Comment: (The above fills in the *one* available type parameter with *one* type that just happens to have *two* available type parameters of its own.)

Comment: Anthony is correct.  Arity simply means the number of arguments is not correct.  The compiler expects you to provide exactly one type parameter when implementing IEnumerable<T> because IEnumerable<T> has exactly one type paramter.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: I just realized there was a typo in my posted (not original) code.  I am in fact attempting to implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<T, int>>`.

Comment: Your error message looks like it wouldn't be generated by the code you posted. You should post the rest of your code. Perhaps you are trying to create a `T` instance somewhere?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Arity is a fancy way of saying "the number of parameters". That's the root of words "binary" (taking two parameters), "unary" (taking one parameter), and "ternary" (taking three parameters).
2. No, not quite: LINQ is rooted in functional programming, and functional programming hates all state, preferring functions with no side effects. Unfortunately, your counter keeps state: that's the `counts` dictionary that you modify, which is a side effect.
3. If you want to count things by key, LINQ already offers you adequate facilities to do so.

Here is how you can get item counts by key:

```
var counters = keyedData
    .GroupBy(item => item.MyKey)
    .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count());
```

Comment: Thanks.  I do not understand a few points.  #2: I can use Linq on a `Dictionary<K,V>`, which keeps as much state as my `Counter<T>`.  My type really only presents a convenient wrapper.  How is my type different?  #3: `Counter<T>` only has one entry per concrete key.  How will Count() act on it?

Comment: @EricJ. `Dictionary<K,V>` is *produced* as the output of a LINQ statement. The dictionary is "manufactured", and then given to you. If you call `ToDictionary` again, a new instance would be manufactured. On the other hand, `counter` is modified in the process of iterating through the input. If you choose to iterate twice, the counters would be incremented twice. If you choose to stop iterating in the middle of the sequence, part of the elements would not be counted.

Comment: @EricJ. On #3, `keyedData` is what you supply to your `Counter<T>`, not the `counter`. It does the same thing: groups by, and counts the number of items in each group. Basically, that's your `counter` re-implemented without an explicit dictionary (of course it's there in LINQ's implementation, but you have no access to it, and it's local to the `ToDictionary` method, so it's returned to you in its complete form, i.e. with everything counted).

Comment: Iterating does not change what is stored in my type's backing dictionary.  I must be misunderstanding something... In reality I am accumulating a large amount of data.  Grouping every single event at runtime would represent an unacceptable performance hit.  I'm not sure whether that's what you are suggesting.

Comment: @EricJ. I may have misunderstood what you were trying to do. If you accumulate large amounts of data upfront, and then you need to make that data available to LINQ, then what you've got now is 100% fine: it compiles and runs on ideone ([link](http://ideone.com/DLilFJ)), doing what it is supposed to do.

Comment: @EricJ. Initially I thought that you were planning to use your `Counter<T>` in a chain of LINQ calls during the iteration to accumulate the counters. The problems I was talking about would happen if `Counter<T>` is in the middle of the LINQ chain. If it is at either of the two ends of the chain, however, then it should be fine.

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications.  The posted code is a simplification of the real code.  Perhaps there is a nuance that I over-simplified.  I'll review the actual code with the benefit of your explanation and see what I can find.